# Extra Columns While Converting Linq Result into Data Table

Tags: c#, linq

When I convert a Linq result into a data table using method below, I get some extra columns!!!

```
private static DataTable LinqQueryToDataTable(IEnumerable<dynamic> v)
{
    var firstRecord = v.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstRecord == null)
        return null;
    PropertyInfo[] infos = firstRecord.GetType().GetProperties();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (var info in infos)
    {

        Type propType = info.PropertyType;

        if (propType.IsGenericType
            && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType));
        }
        else
        {
            table.Columns.Add(info.Name, info.PropertyType);
        }
    }
    DataRow row;
    foreach (var record in v)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            row[i] = infos[i].GetValue(record,null) != null ? infos[i].GetValue(record,null) : DBNull.Value;
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    table.AcceptChanges();
    return table;
}
```

For example if Linq result has 5 columns the data table will have 6 or more columns with extra data, I need to skip and delete extra generated columns.
How to do it? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if I connect the result into a grid view everything is OK, but after converting into DataTable, those extra columns will cause error. Their name are for example DataBase TableNames, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example if Linq result has 5 columns the data table will have 6 or more columns with extra data

Apparently what you call "Linq result" has these "columns". You can easily check the Linq function that provides that or the parameter `v` itself with a debugger.

> if I connect the result into a grid view everything is OK

First, it's not clear what "grid view" you are talking about. Assuming it's a standard WF or WPF data grid view. As usual with UI, what you see there might not be what you get. The UI components does not use directly reflection as in your code, but `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` services. One standard behavior is to suppress properties with `BrowsableAttribute` = No, which I suspect is your case. But without having your actual Linq result, we can only guess - you are the only one who can check that out.

Anyway, if you are in WF, you can use the following:

```
private static DataTable LinqQueryToDataTable(IEnumerable<dynamic> v)
{
    var firstRecord = v.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstRecord == null)
        return null;
    var infos = ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(v);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor info in infos)
    {
        Type propType = info.PropertyType;

        if (propType.IsGenericType
            && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType));
        }
        else
        {
            table.Columns.Add(info.Name, info.PropertyType);
        }
    }
    DataRow row;
    foreach (var record in v)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            row[i] = infos[i].GetValue(record) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    table.AcceptChanges();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: for example think we have a simple query which get all of a table's records. The table name is "Jobs", we have 3 fields in this table. In output DataTable using method above, we have see a output result which has 4 fields. First 3 fields are normal and must be exist. But 4th filed is an extra filed with the name of table and contains some information about database in it. For example "ID","Name","City" and "Jobs",  I do not want to get that last filed named "jobs"

Comment: I think the problem is Here: PropertyInfo[] infos = firstRecord.GetType().GetProperties();

Comment: Hmm, isn't supposed all the items to be of one and the same type? What really is that `v' - Entity objects, anonymous types, or? Linq result is too broad term.

Comment: I think I should control "propType.IsGenericType" in if statement, the extra column is a type of DBML. But I do not know What should i check to not adding this extra column.

Comment: Currently I have a list of Table names and after generating Data Table I will Remove every column which its name is one of table names to remove all of those extra columns